# How can i specify the color of a bar in a bar chart by its value?

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

Well, i created a bar chart and now i want to specify the color of a bar depending of its value on y-axis. simplified- if the value is positive the bar should be red and is the value nagative the bar should be blue.

For me it's only possible to change the color along the x-axis but not the y-axis.

```py
from bokeh.palettes import plasma

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'date' : pd.to_datetime(df_data['date'], format='%Y-%m'), 'values' : df_data['values'], 'color' : plasma(256)})

p = figure(x_axis_label='time',
           x_axis_type='datetime',
           y_axis_label='diff',
           tools = [hover]
           toolbar_location=None
           title="title")

p.vbar(x = 'date',top = 'values', source=source, width=timedelta(days=20), color = 'color')
```

I've found an example on:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

But i need to differentiate or to color the bars by their values no by their number. I know my example makes no sense, but i only want to demonstrate what my expectations are.

Comment: Please provide code to show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution by myself by unsing the cut function of pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = array(df_data['values']).values)
bins = [np.NINF, 0, np.inf]

categories = pd.cut(values, bins, right=False)

palette = ['blue', 'red']

colors = []

for i in categories.codes:
    colors.append[palette[i]]

# Now i can add this column to my ColumnDataSource:
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'date' : pd.to_datetime(df_data['date'], format='%Y-%m'), 'values' : df_data['values'], 'color' : colors}

p.vbar(x = 'date',top = 'values', source=source, width=timedelta(days=20), color = 'colors')
```

Of course this is just as "quick and dirty" solution and there is enough room for optimization.